# Age checker 18+ with regular expressions

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Can you help me please to do age checker with regular expression? I don't know how to calculate if user is 18 or not.
Input: user's birthday (in format of REGEX)
Output: "welcome" or "come back when you will be 18+"

Here is my code for checking if format is ok and bad:

```
import re
import datetime
pattern = re.compile("^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.,_](0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.,_](19|20)\d\d")
dob = input('Enter your birthday (dd/mm/yyyy): ')
result = pattern.match(dob)
if pattern.match(dob):
    print("format is ok")
else:
    print("format is bad")
```

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Since you're calculating the age from a date, why not converting it to a datetime object first and let a lib do the math?

Comment: how to convert from string to date and calculate?

Comment: Like NirO said, using `datetime.strptime()`. But I noticed your comment on that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regex just try to use the input to create a datetime object - if it works the format is good else input is invalid (see datetime.strptime(date_string, format)).
Once you have it and you have datetime.now() you can easily calculate the age

Comment: my senior gave me task to do it with reg expression -_-

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you have the requirement to do it with a regular expression.
Be aware, that this could lead to some edge cases not being covered!

```
import re
import datetime

pattern = re.compile("^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.,_](0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.,_](19|20)\d\d")

dob = input('Enter your birthday (dd/mm/yyyy): ')
result = pattern.match(dob)

if pattern.match(dob):
    print("format is ok")
else:
    print("format is bad")
```

Okay, the regular expression seem to be valid (except the capturing group for the year. You could [use Regexr](https://regexr.com/) or similiar services if you need to refine it).

Then you can deconstruct the matched groups to get the day, month and year:

```
[day, month, year] = result.groups()  # As mentioned, year is currently either 19 or 20
```

Then, the next step would be to compare the month against the current month. This will help decide on whether to add a year or not. In case it happens to be the same or an adjacent month, you might want to look at the days, too.

Finally, subtract the current year from the entered one (once you fixed the year capturing group) and do the math.

Since it's an assignment, I won't provide the code for this ;-)